# laravel change url and id on each loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have something like this:

```
function odeon(){
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565');
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $id = 1;
    foreach($data->listings as $listing){
        $title = $listing->title;
        $time = implode(', ', $listing->times);
        $business_id = 1;
        $film = Film::where('id', $id)->first();
        $id = $id + 1;
        // if news is null
        if (!$film) {
            $film = new Film();
        }
        $film->title = $title;
        $film->times = $time;
        $film->business_id = $business_id;
        $film->save();
    }

    return view('odeon')->with(['listings' => $data->listings]);
}
```

What I want to do is add more cinemas so instead of:

> $data=
>   file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565');
>
> $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/6756');

Be something like:

> $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/6756-10565');

So to go throught from numbers 6756 to 10565, problem is this as well as each cinema has a different business_id I don't want to replicate function for each cinema so any help will be appreciated ;)

Another issue is what if another day therewill be less films than previous day, of course I don't want to display yesturdays films for today

//edit

Ok I will do my best to explain what I want to achieve.

I want to loop throught a cinema, retrieve films for today, save into database, retrieve data for tomorrow save into database, etc. I want to do it for 7 days, Now for each cinema, cinema id + date changes:

https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/10565?day=2017-06-14

Would bring me back films for today, but I want to achieve it for 7 days so something like this:

```
$cinema_id=['10', '20'] (number = cinema_id)
    $startdate = strtotime("today");
    $enddate = strtotime("+7 Days");
    while ($startdate < $enddate) {
        echo date("Y-m-d", $startdate) . "<br>";
        $startdate = strtotime("+1 Days", $startdate);
    }

 $data= file_get_contents (https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/$cinema_id?day=$startdate)
```

So basically I want to loop throught array of cinema and for each cinema_id, go throught 7 days ahead and save details to database. Of course I don't want to keep old records, so each day they either have to be removed or updated

Comment: It seems like you should be using a for loop. You are also setting business_id on every film to the same Id. To not not display yesterdays films add a timestamp and compare today's timestamp if it's older than 12 am today don't show it. If it's younger do show it.

Comment: So how would you put the code together?

Comment: You should also restate your question because it is very hard to understand. I did not down vote but you need to give us more context because we don't reside in your brain.

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what you mean when you concatenate the ids in the url like 6756-10565. If you explain more I will do my best to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague but probably you mean this...

```
function odeon(){
  $arrayOfCinemaIds = [10565,6756];
  foreach($arrayOfCinemaIds as $id){
    //append your id
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/'.$id);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $id = 1;
    foreach($data->listings as $listing){
      $title = $listing->title;
      $time = implode(', ', $listing->times);
      $business_id = 1;
      $film = Film::where('id', $id)->first();
      $id = $id + 1;
      // if news is null
      if (!$film) {
        $film = new Film();
      }
      $film->title = $title;
      $film->times = $time;
      $film->business_id = $business_id;
      $film->save();
    }
    $listings[]=$data->listings;
  }
  //$listings will have all the listings from all the loops
  return view('odeon')->with(['listings' => $listings]);
}
```

You will just need to add more entries to `$arrayOfCimenaIds` as you need. Typically you would load them up from a Db or other data store.

EDIT:
If you have a sequence of numbers you dont need the array you can do

```
for($id=6756;$id<=10565;$id++){..}
```

instead of the `foreach()`

Comment: Can you check my edit on how to include date so it searched 7 days ahead? what happens if 1 day cinema has 5 films and other day it has 7?

Comment: yeah you just need to nest another loop. Your while should work. It would be inside the foreach/for and wrapping the `foreach($data->listing..`

Comment: Can I kindly ask you to update a loop so it includes the date loop? I am sure this code will help not only me! I will also have to include a data for each film so for today do $film->date = $startdate?